How to Play a Redirected Video Link with a Token Using AVPlayer in Swift
I’m working on an iOS video app using AVPlayer, and I’m trying to play a video hosted on a server with the link http://video.vod.testing.ts. However, the server responds with a 302 redirect, and the redirected link contains a long token for authentication.
Here’s the issue:
•   When I try to pass the original link (http://video.vod.testing.ts) to AVPlayer, it doesn’t work because it doesn’t handle the redirection properly.
•   The new redirected link has a token appended to it, and I think I need to handle this manually to ensure the video plays.
Any guidance on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated!

Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

Use NSURLSession to do your authentication, then pass the URL with the extra token to AVPlayer?

I try to pass the the url I receive with the token but still no work
